# How to use multiple layouts in a single activity on android?

Tags: android, android-layout

How do we use multiple layouts in one xml or by Java class??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use `include`

Check [this link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html)

Hope this may help you

**Update**

Check [this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html) as the above one is not accessible now

Comment: yes thnxalot , but can you please give me any sample project about my this problem ?

Comment: http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.in/2010/01/including-layouts-working-example.html

Comment: sonu thomas its working thnx :)

Comment: its so simple actually I have used hide and show the relative layout on to the parent :)